# Migrate Django App from Heroku to Linux Server

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I had my Django app running on Heroku, but now I want to migrate it to my own web server. Everything went fine except the PostgreSQL database: I exported the database from Heroku and imported the dump file into my own PostgreSQL. When I run `python manage.py syncdb` i get the following error:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: no schema has been selected to create in`

When I open any page in my browser I get this error:

```
relation "django_session" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ession_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_se...
```

What is the best way to migrate the app (and the database)?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have a public schema in your database. Run this in your database to create it:

```
CREATE SCHEMA public;
```

After that you don't need to run syncdb, just run:

```
./manage.py migrate
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i tried that before but the schema already exists:

    postgres=# create schema public;
    ERROR:  schema "public" already exists

Comment: I followed a setup tutorial that told me to type (after going into my database with  \c mydb) REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC; - this led to the same error you were having, I just went back in and typed GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public to PUBLIC; and it worked